# How can I implement AsSpan() on a class that holds native memory?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a type that holds some native memory.  I want to implement `AsSpan()` on it so that the native memory can be accessed safely.

Below is a naïve attempt that shows what I'm trying to do.  Clearly `Span<T>` won't keep the holder object alive because it has only the pointer to the native memory and not a reference to the holder object.  I have also tried implementing `MemoryManager<T>` but I can't see how to make `Span<T>` keep the manager object alive either.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Span<byte> span = GetSpan();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        span[span.Length - 1] = 0;  // Access violation
    }

    private static Span<byte> GetSpan()
    {
        Span<byte> span = new Holder(1 << 20).AsSpan();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        span[span.Length - 1] = 0;  // OK
        return span;
    }
}

public class Holder
{
    private readonly int _size;
    private readonly IntPtr _pointer;

    public Holder(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        _pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_size);
    }

    ~Holder()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_pointer);
        Debug.WriteLine("{0:X} was freed", _pointer);
    }

    public Span<byte> AsSpan()
    {
        unsafe { return new Span<byte>((void*)_pointer, _size); }
    }
}
```

`Span<T>` is able to keep managed objects like `String` or `byte[]` alive.  Is there a way to implement `AsSpan()` on a native-memory-holder type so that  `Span<T>` keeps the holder object alive?

Comment: have you seen `System.Memory.Memory`?

Comment: Yes.  `Memory<T>` can keep a `MemoryManager<T>` alive, but you have to turn `Memory<T>` into `Span<T>` in order to get at the memory, so I'm back to the same problem where `Span<T>` won't keep the manager/holder alive if the `Memory<T>` is collected.

Comment: this seems like a use for `IDisposable`, not the finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30877), the lifetime of unmanaged memory cannot be controlled using `Span<T>`.

You can implement `MemoryManager<T>` to manage the lifetime of the unmanaged memory, use it in a `using` block, and as long as the `Span<T>` doesn't escape the using block, it will be safe.  (But it is not possible to force the API consumer to use the API safely.)

Comment: Yes, I think that's a fair assessment. If the actual span was an interior pointer to a managed object, then: fine. But as a raw pointer to unmanaged memory, there is indeed nothing to keep it alive. You're just going to have to keep hold of the holder somewhere at least as long as the span is active. BTW, I would strongly suggest using `MemoryManager<T>` as the source of a span - this one should work: https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/master/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs